# Requirements to use Memcached with Java on windows xp

Tags: java, windows-xp, memcached, spymemcached

What are the requirements for the memcached to be used through java on windows xp?
Currently i m using memcached 1.4.4 as a service , 
                    eclipse ganymede, 
                    spymemcached 2.8.0. 
But i m having problems in setting keys and connection disconnects unexpectedly and try to reconnect.

Do i require any other software or service like libevent to be used along with them?

Comment: Hey Guys, 
Do i need to add any configuration file with my java code to give it path or some info about memcached server???

Comment: Can you telnet into your memcached server and set keys?

http://lzone.de/articles/memcached.htm

Comment: when i connect telnet ... i only get a blank screen... and cursor moves blank when i type in something...

Comment: I'm not familiar with memcached on windows, but if telnet is not working for you then there is definitely a problem with your installation. I have never installed memcached on Windows so I don't think I can be of further help. An alternative that I know will work for you is to use Couchbase server and use a memcached bucket. This will run Couchbase with as memcached server and provide a nice web interface. It should be very easy to install on Windows too. (Note: I am a Couchbase employee)

Comment: problem is we are already using Jboss server and having another server to deploy would be not much of efficiency.. I worked woth couchbase... It has quite gud interface on localhost:8091  but not really what we want. As far as i know , i should be focussing on the memcached to run along with my java code ... Thanks for your help Mike.. couchbase is really cool BTW....